# CMPedometer getting error in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, swift2, core-motion

I cannot invoke start pedometer updates from date with an argument list of type.

It was working in Swift 1.2, but now since I migrated to Swift 2, it is getting an error.

```
 if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()){
        self.manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
        self.coremotion.startPedometerUpdatesFromDate(NSDate()) {
          (data: CMPedometerData!, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if(error == nil){
                    println(data.numberOfSteps)
                    self.pedoLabel.text = "\(data.numberOfSteps)"
                    self.label.text = ("Great you have \(data.numberOfSteps) steps")
                }
            })   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some Code and explain exactly where your Problem lies. It's hard to tell by now.

Comment: @MiBrock  i just added code can you please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Optional: (data: CMPedometerData?, error)

```
if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()){
    self.manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
    self.coremotion.startPedometerUpdatesFromDate(NSDate()) {
      (data: CMPedometerData?, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if(error == nil){
                println(data.numberOfSteps)
                self.pedoLabel.text = "\(data.numberOfSteps)"
                self.label.text = ("Great you have \(data.numberOfSteps) steps")
            }
        })   
    }
}
```